# "prompted me to something" or "prompted me something"

Tags: word-usage

> prompted me to something

or

> prompted me something

What is the correct way: "it prompted me to something" or "it prompted me something"?

Answer (score 1):

*Prompt me **to** [verb infinitive]* means that someone or something *tells* you to do something, or *reminds you*, or *makes you decide to do something*.

*Prompt me* is like a less specific version, it's more about the action of *prompting* itself, not what the result is. You can also *provide a prompt* (a more explicit action, like telling a person what to say, or popping up a box on the screen and asking the user to take action). And you can *prompt someone **with** [something]*, where you're describing *the thing* you're using as a prompt.

*Prompt me [something]* isn't ever used, as far as I can tell. If you're describing the prompt, use *prompt me with "bla bla"*. If you're describing the action the prompt is encouraging, use *prompt me to [verb]*

Comment: Ohh okay! Thank you so much! Great explanation! So saying that "my sadness prompted me deep stories" is wrong, right?

Comment: @MariaZildaRibeiro yeah, I'm not sure exactly what you mean! If you're saying the sadness caused you to *create* or *imagine* or *come up with* deep stories, then you can use those verbs with *prompt* like in my first example. If you can explain what you mean, what you're going for, I might be able to give you a better sentence

Comment: You could say *my sadness prompted me **with** deep stories*, I don't *exactly* know what that means but it *sounds like* the sadness makes the person imagine stories, and those stories prompt them to do things. This is getting into more poetic language, so you have more freedom to say things in unusual ways, to get across an idea and a feeling. A lot of great writing is open to interpretation! And in that sense, your original *my sadness prompted me deep stories* line *could* work - but it would be unusual and poetic, the meaning might not be clear, and it would be non-standard English